# Tramp (from straight) fails in emacs 29

Tags: tramp, straight.el

After switching to fc39, emacs fails to load tramp via my use-package statement:

```
(straight-use-package 'use-package)
(setq straight-use-package-by-default t)
...
(use-package tramp)
```

The error is as follows (including build warnings):

```
⛔ Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/rob/.emacs.d/init.el’:

Symbol's function definition is void: tramp--with-startup

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
⛔ Warning (comp): /home/rob/.emacs.d/straight/build/tramp/tramp-sudoedit.el: Error: Symbol's function definition is void make-tramp-file-name
⛔ Warning (comp): /home/rob/.emacs.d/straight/build/tramp/tramp.el: Error: Symbol's function definition is void make-tramp-file-name
⛔ Warning (comp): /home/rob/.emacs.d/straight/build/tramp/tramp-sshfs.el: Error: Symbol's function definition is void make-tramp-file-name

[trimmed a bunch more]

⛔ Warning (comp): /home/rob/.emacs.d/straight/build/tramp/.dir-locals.el: Error: Wrong type argument proper-list-p
⛔ Warning (comp): /home/rob/.emacs.d/straight/build/tramp/test/tramp-tests.el: Error: Symbol's function definition is void make-tramp-file-name
```

When I run emacs with --debug-init, it shows a backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function tramp--with-startup)
  (tramp--with-startup (add-to-list 'tramp-methods `(,tramp-adb-method (tramp-login-program ,tramp-adb-program) (tramp-login-args (("-s" "%d") ("shell"))) (tramp-direct-async t) (tramp-tmpdir "/data/local/tmp") (tramp-default-port 5555))) (add-to-list 'tramp-default-host-alist `(,tramp-adb-method nil "")) (tramp-set-completion-function tramp-adb-method '((tramp-adb-parse-device-names ""))))
  straight--activate-package-autoloads((:type git :host github :repo "emacs-straight/tramp" :files ("*" (:exclude ".git")) :package "tramp" :local-repo "tramp"))
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x12c70fbf29c936da>)()
  straight--transaction-exec(use-package-\"cb4d6d9f3d2ff3fe32638a8f6530f986\"-nil-nil :now #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x12c70fbf29c936da>))
  straight-use-package(tramp)
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/rob/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/rob/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/rob/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x2fc7bacaf404b8>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b39f5>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I updated tramp by means of a straight-pull-package, but it doesn't change anything. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs 29.1 has an error when installing Tramp from GNU ELPA. See its [home page](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/tramp.html) for a mitigation recipe.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I tried to mess with the suggested solution, but I'm far from elisp-literate and couldn't get it to work. From what I found in a related devel thread, it should be fixed in 29.2, so I'll just wait for that :)